# How to use cumulative sum calculated by pivot table, at another measure

Tags: excel, powerpivot, cumulative-sum

I have the following pivot table constructed.

[image: Original Data]

I changed "Total Customer" to the following format using "Show Value as Running Total in". It is the exactly what I want.

[image: Running Total]

What I want to do next is I want to calculate the percentage by "Active Customer/ Total Customer". I tried to calculate it by adding measure [Count of Active Customer] / [Count of Total Customer] but it only calculate the total customer from first image values (not as the running total in the second). So, How I can calculate "Active Customer / Total Customer (Running total)" as the additional measure.

Comment: You will have to create measures for the running totals.

Comment: how may I do that? do I need to build that measure (field) in data source or is there a quick way to do that.

Comment: You create it in the data model using power pivot. The actual formulas involved will depend on your data set and which fields you want the totals to calculate within. There are numerous examples online of creating running totals in power pivot